# Binary logistic regression and percentage change variable

Tags: logistic, binary-data, percentage

I am a student approaching binary logistic analysis. I was wondering whether the independent variables used in the logistic regression can be expressed in percentage changes. If yes, How to interprete the OR?

Thanks so much for any help!
Matias

Comment: An odds-ratio effect of say $3$ will change a probability of $1\%$ to almost $3\%$ but a probability of $50\%$ to $75\%$.  So in any particular case you can say what the effect is on the probability but it depends on the starting probability

Answer (score 1):

You can always input any variable you want into logistic regression, however, you then need to do the math to associate the variable's units with the regression coefficients and if exponentiated, how those units relate to OR.  Regarding use of a per cent change input variable, logistic reg makes no assumptions about the distribution of input variables -- so you're ok there.

As an alternative, ORs from logistic regression are commonly derived from binary (0,1) variables like yes/no, exposed/nonexposed, treated/placebo, etc.  If you took this approach, you would recode (binarize) your per cent change variable into a new variable with a 1 representing per cent change above the median, and 0 representing below the median.  Then you'd rerun the model using that binary variable as a predictor with/without other covariates, and then simply exponentiate the regression coef for the binary variable, $OR=\exp(\beta)$ to get the OR.  Once done, the conclusion would be: "the OR for having $y=1$ for objects with a per cent change above the median (e.g. high value of per cent change) is XX.XX."